# Facing Error in installing python httpclient

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install httpclient library

```
    $ sudo pip install httpclient
......
        urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /mnt/tmp/pip-build-C8co4C/httpclient/
```

Upgraded setup tools but still httpclient is not installing.

Comment: Try to install OpenSSL with `apt-get install openssl` or the equivalent for your distribution.

Comment: Tried... Same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install SSH with pip ?

If not, you can do it following this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

And if it's still not solving your issue, you can always [download](https://pypi.org/project/httpclient/#files) and add the package manually (but not ideal).